# Start playing an audio CD in Deadbeef player with a command

Tags: command, audio-cd, deadbeef

This question is created to share a simple and interesting solution related to this great player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://github.com/Alexey-Yakovenko/deadbeef/issues/1459#issuecomment-174975377), the command is

```
deadbeef all.cda
```